# Simple circle on Google maps doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sorry for the stupid question but i don't understand why the code doesn't work...

```
var centro= new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
 var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  center: centro,
  radius: 1000
});
// Add the circle for this city to the map.
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: The [posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/j6m03k3a/) works for me.

Comment: sorry, you are right... i forgot that radius it isn't in km, and so i didn't see the circle :D thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you...

```
var circleOptions = {
   strokeColor: '#FF0000',
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 2,
   fillColor: '#FF0000',
   fillOpacity: 0.35,
   map: map,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(surveyors[i][5], surveyors[i][6]),
   radius: ddlRadius_value * 1609.345 // convert miles to kilometers
};

// Add the circle to the map.
var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

// Bind the center of the circle to the marker                    
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Answer (score 0):

You've centered your circle at (0,0), i.e. on the equator a bit west of Africa.  Is that spot visible at all, in your map at its current position and zoom?

Also, the radius parameter is in meters.  If you're zoomed out enough, your 1000-meter-radius circle will simply be too small to see.